# Error al insertar una entidad desde Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

Estoy tratando de realizar una inserción de una nueva entidad por medio de  `Entity Framework` `C#`  en una tabla con Id auto-generado, pero al realizar la llamada al método `SaveChanges()` recibo el siguiente error:

> **A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: `Id`.**

Revisando en Base de datos, está correctamente definido como auto-numérico y en el `.edmx` aparece como `PK`.
¿Alguna idea donde puede estar el error?

Comment: Hola Kram_, bienvenid@ a la familia de SOes, sería de mucha ayuda para ti el hecho de colocar mayor información, como mostrar el diagrama edmx, el código que has realizado, así podremos facilitarte una respuesta con mayor precisión. Saludos :D

Comment: Puedes ser que hiciste un cambio en la base de datos, pero se te olvido eliminar y actualizar el entity framework en tu codigo

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas probable es que esa tabla se este relacionando con alguna otra causando el fallo al persistir, porque por lo que entiendo del mensaje pareciera ser que una relacion con otra tabla es la que cusa el problema.

Es por eso que menciona el "*ReferentialConstraint*" el mensaje de error.

Aqui

[A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384659/a-dependent-property-in-a-referentialconstraint-is-mapped-to-a-store-generated-c)

se plantea lo mismo que comento, valida que las relaciones de esta tabla con alguna otra este correcta